# Configuring 5 node Kafka cluster on Linux RHEL7.5 Virtul Machine

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, storage, rhel7, kafka-cluster

I am configuring 5 node Kafka cluster on Linux RHEL7.5 Virtual Machine. 
 Can anybody suggest which Storage Type I have to use SAN or NAS ?